# Why specifying "user-provided" constructor makes the class non-aggregate?

Tags: c++, c++20, default-constructor

I came across this example from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization#Example):

```
...

struct T3
{
    int mem1;
    std::string mem2;
    T3() {} // user-provided default constructor
}

...
```

This example clearly show that the given constructor is *user-provided* constructor since it's not explicitly defaulted or deleted on its first declaration; per [dcl.fct.def.default]/5:

> [..] A function is user-provided if it is user-declared and not
> explicitly defaulted or deleted on its first declaration [..]

Now, Per [dcl.init.aggr]/1

> An aggregate is an array or a class (Clause 11) with
>
> - (1.1) — no user-declared or inherited constructors (11.4.5),
> - (1.2) — no private or protected direct non-static data members (11.8),
> - (1.3) — no virtual functions (11.7.3), and
> - (1.4) — no virtual, private, or protected base classes (11.7.2).

It seems that my class satisfy all the above requirements to be an aggregate including the point (1.1) since the given constructor is not user-declared.

So why the following code it ill-formed (tested on g++12.2 with c++20 flag):

```
static_assert(std::is_aggregate<T3>::value); // fail
```

Why static assertion is failed?

Comment: " A function is user-provided if it is user-declared and not explicitly defaulted or deleted on its first declaration [..]" means your constructor is user-provided (and user-declared)

Comment: default constructor would be `= default`

Comment: All function definitions are also declarations of the function.

Comment: _"This example clearly shows that the given constructor is user-provided constructor"_ and shows also that the given constructor is _user-declared_

Comment: I don't quite follow your line of reasoning. In the beginning you state "This example clearly show that the given constructor is user-provided " and quote "A function is user-provided if it is user-declared and..." and then later "since the given constructor is not user-declared." why do you think it would be not a user-declared constructor?

Comment: A user provided constructor is also a user declared constrcutor.

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik it is a "default constructor" just not a defaulted default constructor ;)

Comment: The fact that your default construct has an *empty* body doesn't mean that it isn't user-provided. Even if that's effectively the same as the defaulted (compiler-provided) constructor, it is *still* a user-provided constructor.

Comment: "Why specifying "user-provided" constructor makes the class non-aggregate?" - Because the C++ standard says so

Answer (score 8):

Because a user-provided constructor is a user-declared constructor.

It is right there in the part you quote:

> [..] A function is user-provided if it is user-declared and not explicitly defaulted or deleted on its first declaration [..]

Only a user-declared constructor can be a user-provided constructor. A user-declared constructor is user-provided when it is not explicitly defaulted or deleted on its first declaration.

```
T3() {}         // I   user-provided, user-declared 
T3() = default; // II  user-declared, not user-provided
T3() = delete;  // III user-declared, not user-provided
```

Terms can be a little confusing. All 3 declare a default constructor (one that can be called without parameters). Only `II` is a defaulted constructor (definition is generated by compiler).

PS: Thanks to @John for clarifying that also

```
T3();     // IV user-declared, user-provided
```

Is user-declared and user-provided, even if later it might be defined via

```
T3::T3() = default;
```

Because according to the definition it is user-provided when (it is user-declared and) it is not explicitly defaulted or deleted **on its first declaration**.

Comment: `I` is user-provided. And `struct S{ S(); } S::S() = default` is also user-provided. Right?

Comment: @SofaJoe note that the specification for aggregate type doesnt mention user-provided. It rules out user-declared constructors, ie `struct S {};` is an aggregate.

Comment: _"And `struct S{ S(); } S::S() = default` is also user-provided."_ It is user-provided explicitly-defaulted constructor. Hence `S` is not an aggregate.

Comment: The standard gives you an example: `struct nontrivial1 {
nontrivial1(); // first declaration
};
nontrivial1::nontrivial1() = default; // not first declaration`

Comment: @SofaJoe - And `I` is user-provided user-declared constructor

Comment: @SofaJoe: All things which are "user-provided" are *also* "user declared".

Comment: @John thanks for the input, its much clearer to me now. I added a part to the answer, hope I got it right

Answer (score 1):

Take the quote you quoted literally:

A function is *user-provided* if,

- that function is *user-declared* function, and
- that function is not explicitly defaulted  on its first
  declaration, or
- that function is not explicitly deleted on its first
  declaration.

Considering the quote above, and heading to [dcl.init.aggr]/1

> An aggregate is an array or a class (Clause 11) with
>
> (1.1) — no user-declared or inherited constructors (11.4.5), [..]

And since your class has a user-declared constructor, which is a user-provided constructor by definition, your assertion fails.